# Changing SFDC orgs within Service Cloud for Slack fails - We can't connect Salesforce to Slack

Tags: slack-salesforce-app

After successfully connecting Service Cloud for Slack app to my Dev Org, I went to disconnect and then connect to my staging org. This as per

- Staging org had all the Slack permissions established; T&C accepted
- Staging org had Swarming enabled and Service Cloud for Slack enabled
- Staging Collaboration tool was defined as Slack

Result was error: `We can't connect Salesforce to Slack`

How do I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YMMV** but here is what I did

1. Examined `Personal Settings > Slack User Mappings` in the dev org (this would see if Slack still connected to the Dev Org despite me disconnecting within the Slack app's `Manage Org` button

   - RESULT: empty list
2. Contacted SFDC Support *(I don't normally give up so easily before calling Support, but as it turned out, turfing to Support was the correct action)*

Basically, SFDC Support determined that, in their words ...

> I have checked from backend and there is old routing data connected
> and thus you are facing this error.

To correct this, you need to supply your Slack workspace Id that begins with a `T`. This is not trivial as

- It is not ascertainable from any property on your workspace that you can see in the Slack app *(it is ascertainable if you have other users successfully connected to the org by examining `Setup > Slack User Mappings` but in my case, I was the first user)*
- If you go to the browser, and choose your workspace, you'll get something like: `https://app.slack.com/client/Exxxxxxxxx/Cxxxxxxxxx` and the SFDC Support staff has to have an Id starting with `T` *(or at least my support agent did)*

  - So, I used Chrome Developer Tools and traced the redirects once I chose the workspace from `app.slack.com` and got this `https://app.slack.com/client/Txxxxxxxxx/Dxxxxxxxxx`
- With the `Txxxxxxxxx` value, SFDC Support was able to clean up the routing tables

> Good news !!
>
> We have successfully removed the old routing. can you please try to connect the Service Cloud for Slack to the sandbox.

- I then tried connecting from the `Service Cloud for Slack` app again, logging into my staging org.

  - The initial attempt resulted in a GACK *(oh no!)*
  - A second attempt yielded a success and the `Personal Settings  > Slack User Mapping` is now correct (as well as a success dialog box)

[image]